# D3.js: Using images (with filenames specified in data) as tick values on axis

Tags: javascript, json, image, d3.js

I currently have this data:

```
var dataset = [
{
 "bank": "Bank 1",
 "img": "Picture1.png"
},
{
 "bank": "Bank 2",
 "img": "Picture2.png"
},                  
{
 "bank": "Bank 3",
 "img": "Picture3.png"
}
];
```

Complex real-world data, right?  Sure.  OK, I currently have "**bank**" as the tick values on my axis with this D3.js code:

```
var w = 1000;
var h = 700;
var padding = 30;
var wpadding = 120;
var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h+padding);

var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
                .domain(dataset.map(function (d) { return d.bank; }))
                .rangeRoundBands([0, h], 0.55);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(yScale)
                .orient("left");

    svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + wpadding + ", 0)")
                .call(yAxis);
```

Anyway, I'm sure you can see where I'm going with this.  I'm now trying to make the tick values on my axis reference the ***img*** value in my dataset, rather than just the ***bank*** value.

At first I thought it was a case of using *axis.tickValues([values])* with an anonymous function to reference the ***img*** values in my JSON data, but it's not working.  Or I'm doing it horribly wrong.

Then I thought it was a case of using:

```
 var imgs = svg.selectAll("img").data([dataset]);
```

but then my concern with this method is that this won't be properly bound to the axis, like proper tick values; It's like they're just a collection of images which happen to be sitting next to my axis, and sizing/positioning changes I make to my axis I have to separately apply to my collection of images as well.  It just doesn't seem as elegant as having proper images-as-tick-values-on-my-axis.

Am I doing something horribly wrong?  Does anyone need me to provide more info?

Thanks again gals & guys!

**UPDATE**: Thanks to @larskotthoff , I've added this:

```
svg.select(".axis").selectAll("text").remove();

var ticks = svg.select(".axis").selectAll(".tick")
                    .data(dataset)
                    .append("svg:image")
                    .attr("xlink:href", function (d) { return d.img ; })
                    .attr("width", 100)
                    .attr("height", 100);
```

And it (almost) works!  Well, it shows images, but as you can guess, the origin point of each image (ie., their top-left corner) is where each tick ends, resulting in the image now rendering inside the diagram, instead of outside of it beside the tick:

*can't insert images without enough StackOverflow rep, so here's the URL: i.stack.imgur.com/s2CX0.png*
*Tick image appears inside diagram instead of alongside tick*

Clearly I need to manipulate the images' x's and y's, but how do I do that relative to the position of the individual tick?  In other words, how do I say in D3: "*Take the x,y of the tick and subtract (a hardcoded value of) 150 for both, and make that my new x,y for my image.*" ?

Thanks again for your help!

**UPDATE #2**:  After finally discovering *this.parentNode* and digging into it, I just newbie-ly discovered that the x,y attributes as set on the images current bound to my axis are relative to each respective tick!  By that I mean, I can just simply add:

```
                    .attr("x", -120)
                    .attr("y", -50);
```

as additional attributes for my images, and it positions them to the left of their respective ticks (back on the axis label position, not sitting on top of the diagram).

Comment: Hmmm, it sounds like you would need to select the existing tick label `text` elements, remove them and replace with `image` elements set to the correct URL based on the data bound to the `text` elements.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff -- thanks for your suggestion!  I've updated my OP with more info.

Comment: You can take the `transform` attribute, extract `translate` and modify those relative coordinates.

Comment: Thanks again @LarsKotthoff, I've now discovered how to access parent nodes in multiple selections!

Comment: Hi @user3683920, I followed you solution and got the images on the screen. But they are not visible for some reason. I can see their shape when I inspect element, but their blocked or hidden or something. Any idea?

Comment: How do you want to put the images on the screen, like a table or in a particular layout?

Comment: it sounds like this question is answered, by yourself. It's totally acceptable to write an answer in reply to your own question. I think that would be useful as it would no longer appear in unanswered questions :)

Comment: How appropriate is it to post the OP's answer since they don't appear to be following up with doing that?

Comment: @morganpdx go for it. Totally appropriate

Answer (score 6):

Dataset:

```
var dataset = [
{
 "bank": "Bank 1",
 "img": "Picture1.png"
},
{
 "bank": "Bank 2",
 "img": "Picture2.png"
},                  
{
 "bank": "Bank 3",
 "img": "Picture3.png"
}
];
```

D3 JS code:

```
var w = 1000;
var h = 700;
var padding = 30;
var wpadding = 120;
var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h+padding);


svg.select(".axis").selectAll("text").remove();

var ticks = svg.select(".axis").selectAll(".tick")
                    .data(dataset)
                    .append("svg:image")
                    .attr("xlink:href", function (d) { return d.img ; })
                    .attr("width", 100)
                    .attr("height", 100);
                    .attr("x", -120);
                    .attr("y", -50);


var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
                .domain(dataset.map(function (d) { return d.bank; }))
                .rangeRoundBands([0, h], 0.55);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(yScale)
                .orient("left");

    svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + wpadding + ", 0)")
                .call(yAxis);
```